# Regex find at least one of two characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Bear with me, I am new to regular expressions, so my syntax may be slightly out.

Here is my expression:

```
"(?:\\s*[\"]?[']?\\s*)"
```

Which equates to: Any amount of white space, then the possibility of a double quote, then the possibility of a single quote, then any amount of white space.

The problem I have is that this still matches even if there is no double quote or single quote.

How do I make my expression so that there must be at least 1 double quote OR at least 1 single quote?

Comment: http://www.regexper.com/ - put it in here - and all will be clear! :D

Comment: At least 1 double or 1 single, or EXACTLY 1 (double or single)? If more than one quote is allowed in total, do all the quotes need to be consecutive for the pattern to match as a whole?

Comment: @DaveBish, What an excellent tool! I will be using this ALOT in future! :-)

Comment: @Jon, say I have:     "     :      " or       '   :\t', it should match to this. Basically I want: Find any whitespace, followed by 1, and only 1 double quote or single quote, then any further whitespace.

Comment: @series0ne: Find any whitespace `\\s*` followed by 1, and only 1 double quote or single quote `(\"|')` then any further whitespace `\\s*`. All together: `\\s*(\"|')\\s*)`. It's not that complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
@"(?:\s*('|\")+\s*)"
```

Comment: In verbatim, shouldn't the double quote be escaped by another double quote character instead of a backslash?
The resulting regular expression would then be `@"(?:\s*('|"")+\s*)"`?

Comment: works! You just taught me something new about regular expressions! Thanks! :-)

Comment: @series0ne: If you only want 1 quote in total, drop the `+` in there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
(?:\\s*[\\"\\']\\s*)
```

:D

Comment: In verbatim strings, you have to mask `"` as `""`, and masking `'` is wrong in any kind of string literal.

Comment: `"(?:\\s*[\"']\\s*)"` or `@"(?:\s*[""']\s*)"` would be correct, as well as `(?:\s*["']\s*)`. That regex was better before your fix ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to find one single or one double quote then just put both inside a character group and don't put a question mark after it.

`(?:\s*[\"']\s*)`

If you mean you want 1 or more single quotes or 1 or more double quotes

`(?:\s*([\"]+)|([']+)\s*)`

If you mean you want 1 or more single or double quotes

`(?:\s*[\"']+\s*)`

Comment: Thanks, this elaborates a lot on what I need, but that's a good thing! Now I have a reference of three different scenarios, as will any other developer that hits this page.